# "Insert if doesn't exist" only for product type = 'product' in post_meta table WP

Tags: mysql, wordpress, insert, woocommerce

I found several explanations about how to "insert".... "where not exists", but it doesn't solve my problem.

I'm using Wordpress and I have a table named wp_posts with data of posts, products, product_variations, attachments, etc

I have to run a query in mysql to create a custom field in wp_postmeta with the name of "_special_stock" and the value of "0" every time a product is created in wp_posts.

I found:

```html
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
    SELECT wp_posts.ID, '_special_stock', '0'
        FROM wp_posts
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT post_id
                              FROM wp_postmeta
                              WHERE post_id=wp_posts.ID)
```

The code works perfectly, but it includes a row not only for products but for other product types as well, and I have to include a condition in order to insert that meta_key (_special_stock) only for products and product_variation, something like this:

```html
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
    SELECT wp_posts.ID, '_stock', '0'
        FROM wp_posts
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT post_id
                              FROM wp_postmeta
                              WHERE post_id=wp_posts.ID)
        WHERE wp_posts.product_type='product' 
        OR wp_posts.product_type='product_variation';
```

But it doesn't work.

Can somebody help me please??

Caio

Answer (score 0):

Nobody answered, but I finally found the solution, thus I want to share with you. I'm not an expert, so I don't know whether it is the best solution or not, but it works for me... :)

```html
BEGIN

INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
SELECT wp_posts.ID, '_stock', '0'
FROM wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT post_id
             FROM wp_postmeta
             WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID);

INSERT IGNORE INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
SELECT wp_posts.ID, '_stock', '0'
FROM wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'product_variation' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT post_id
             FROM wp_postmeta
             WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID);

END
```

I hope this could be useful for anybody else! However, if somebody knows any other way to achieve the result I really appreciate it. I'll try to trigger this statement now in my db after a product is inserted in wp_posts.